# Correct way to set and override a request header in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-http-auth

I need to set a global http header to all my requests because of the authentication method that we are using. We have an Identity Server to authenticate the user using a SSO approach. So far so good, we were using interceptors to set headers globally. But sometimes we need to make a request to a 3rd party API that doesn't use any authentication method.
How can I override the authentication header that was configured by the interceptor?
Is it a recommended approach for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interceptor, you can write some logic to decide if you need to add the header or not:

```
.factory('AuthHeaderInterceptor', function () {

  function request(config) {

    //if 3rd party url, don't add auth header
    if(config.url.indexOf('third_party_url') !== -1) {
      return config;
    }

    config.headers.Authorization = 'auth header';
    return config;
  }

  return {
    request: request
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Now it seems to be so obvious! Probably the best way. Just another thing that I thought but I am not sure if it works: if I create a service to my third party (is this a good thing to do by the way?) can I override the harder or actually it would be overridden in the interceptor?

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm not sure what you mean by "override the harder". As far as I know, the interceptor would catch any HTTP requests (yeah, not only API calls, even requests for css/html/js files). I don't see why creating a service for a third party is a bad idea, I'd say go for it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean override the header.

Comment: Considering your service is still going through angular's `$http` service, yeah, the request would pass through the interceptor.